# How to safely remove a USB device from 2008 Core server?

Tags: usb, hard-drive, device, windows-server-core

I have a Hyper-V Core server 2008 that I administer via command line and remote tools. We have now got a new backup system in place and it involves me connecting an External USB drive (G:) to backup system state files. My question is how should I safely remove the drive for its weekly offsite swap?

I've tried using the devcon tool however it just says the 'removal failed with no devices removed' with no other explanation. I have noticed that there isnt a readily available x64 version of devcon and that might be the cause of the problem. (I have read of people downloading a amd64 version but I have not located it myself, if someone knows where it is please let me know).

The devcon command worked on my old 2003 x86 server with the command: **devcon remove *3200AVJ_EXTERNAL***

I have also looked at using **fsutil volume dismount g:** but it doesn't seem to work as G: is still listed as a connected volume.

I have checked that the volume is not in use via remote tools and the **net file** command. Both show no open files in the G:\ volume. This could be a decent substitute as it might be used to flush any remaining IO to the volume can anyone clarify?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the Windows 2003 version of devcon? I don't think it is 100% compatible with Windows 2008. Try downloading the WDK from Microsoft and extracting the newest version from there. [link text](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/WDK/WDKpkg.mspx)

The newest x64 version is in: `WDK\setuptools_x64fre_cab001.cab` - extract the `_devcon.exe_00000` file and rename to `devcon.exe`. The proper version of the file should be 6.1.7600.16385.